# Debugging UIWEBVIEW in Safari with Swift and Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, uiwebview, swift

I'm currently having trouble enabling safari's debugging tools for a UIWebView.  I'm trying to inspect why certain things are not loading in the UIWebView.

1. The app does not show up in the Safari > Develop > iOS Simulator list.
2. There are no inspectable applications for the app that is
   loaded
3. I'm working with Xcode6-Beta, Mac OSX 10.10, and iOS 8.

I'm specifically looking for an answer that will allow me to debug using safari, or make note that the newest versions of Safari/Xcode don't debug app UIWebviews.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the you can't debug a `UIWebView` using the Mac version of Safari, but I just tested debugging iOS Safari in an iOS 8 simulator using Safari for Mac (OS X 10.9 though) and it worked fine. Are you trying to debug the `UIWebView` or the website itself?

Comment: I'm trying to debug a UIWebView specifically. The website itself isn't producing the same errors.

Answer (score 2):

Wanted to let everyone know that it turns out that the bug I had on my end was on the webapp side not the ios side. Unfortunately I still have not found a way to debug in Safari an iOS 8 simulator.